Quarantining Python code from being updated
I have installed Onboard (virtual keyboard) and it resides in
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Onboard/
I have made some changes to a few of the files (for a modified layout) which I want to quarantine against a system upgrade.
Can I copy the changed files into
/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/Onboard or similar?
What change do I need to make to $PATH to use the changed files while also using the unchanged files from the original location?
